# HLSL modify depth in pixel shader

Tags: c#, directx-11, depth, sharpdx, pixel-shader

I need to render an image (with depth) which I get from outside. I can construct two textures and pass them into a shader with no problem (I can verify values sampled in a pixel shader being correct).

Here's how my HLSL looks like:

```
// image texture
Texture2D m_TextureColor : register(t0);

// depth texture with values [0..1]
Texture2D<float> m_TextureDepth : register(t1);

// sampler to forbid linear filtering since we're dealing with pixels
SamplerState m_TextureSampler { Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT; };

struct VS_IN
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VS_OUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_OUT
{
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float depth : DEPTH0;
};

VS_OUT VS(VS_IN input)
{
    VS_OUT output = (VS_OUT)0;

    output.position = input.position;
    output.texcoord = input.texcoord;

    return output;
}

PS_OUT PS(VS_OUT input) : SV_Target
{
    PS_OUT output = (PS_OUT)0;

    output.color = m_TextureColor.SampleLevel(m_TextureSampler, input.texcoord, 0);

    // I want to modify depth of the pixel,
    // but it looks like it has no effect on depth no matter what I set here
    output.depth = m_TextureDepth.SampleLevel(m_TextureSampler, input.texcoord, 0);

    return output;
}
```

I construct vertex buffer from those (with `PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip`) where first argument `Vector4` is position and second argument `Vector2` is texture coordinate:

```
new[]
{
    new Vertex(new Vector4(-1, -1, 0.5f, 1), new Vector2(0, 1)),
    new Vertex(new Vector4(-1, 1, 0.5f, 1), new Vector2(0, 0)),
    new Vertex(new Vector4(1, -1, 0.5f, 1), new Vector2(1, 1)),
    new Vertex(new Vector4(1, 1, 0.5f, 1), new Vector2(1, 0)),
}
```

Everything works just fine: I'm seeing my image, I can sample depth from depth texture and construct something visual from it (that's how I can verify that 
depth values I'm sampling are correct). However I can't figure out how to modify pixel's depth so that it would be eaten properly when the depth-test would be happening. Because at the moment it all depends on what kind of z value I set as my vertex position.

This is how I'm setting up `DirectX11` (I'm using `SharpDX` and `C#`):

```
var swapChainDescription = new SwapChainDescription
{
    BufferCount = 1,
    ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(bufferSize.Width, bufferSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
    IsWindowed = true,
    OutputHandle = HostHandle,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
};
var swapChainFlags = DeviceCreationFlags.None | DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport;
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, swapChainFlags, swapChainDescription, out var device, out var swapchain);
```

Setting back buffer and depth/stencil buffer:

```
// color buffer
using (var textureColor = SwapChain.GetBackBuffer<Texture2D>(0))
{
    TextureColorResourceView = new RenderTargetView(Device, textureColor);
}

// depth buffer
using (var textureDepth = new Texture2D(Device, new Texture2DDescription
{
    Format = Format.D32_Float,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    Width = BufferSize.Width,
    Height = BufferSize.Height,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
}))
{
    TextureDepthResourceView = new DepthStencilView(Device, textureDepth);
}

DeviceContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(TextureDepthResourceView, TextureColorResourceView);
```

Preparing depth stencil state:

```
var description = DepthStencilStateDescription.Default();
description.DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual;
description.IsDepthEnabled = true;
description.DepthWriteMask = DepthWriteMask.All;
DepthState = new DepthStencilState(Device, description);
```

And using it:

```
DeviceContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(DepthState);
```

This is how I construct my color/depth textures I'm sending to shader:

```
public static (ShaderResourceView resource, Texture2D texture) CreateTextureDynamic(this Device device, System.Drawing.Size size, Format format)
{
    var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
    {
        MipLevels = 1,
        Format = format,
        Width = size.Width,
        Height = size.Height,
        ArraySize = 1,
        BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write,
    };

    var texture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);
    return (new ShaderResourceView(device, texture), texture);
}
```

Also since I need to update them frequently:

```
public static void UpdateResource(this Texture2D texture, int[] buffer, System.Drawing.Size size)
{
    var dataBox = texture.Device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(texture, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None, out var dataStream);
    Parallel.For(0, size.Height, rowIndex => Marshal.Copy(buffer, size.Width * rowIndex, dataBox.DataPointer + dataBox.RowPitch * rowIndex, size.Width));
    dataStream.Dispose();
    texture.Device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(texture, 0);
}

public static void UpdateResource(this Texture2D texture, float[] buffer, System.Drawing.Size size)
{
    var dataBox = texture.Device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(texture, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None, out var dataStream);
    Parallel.For(0, size.Height, rowIndex => Marshal.Copy(buffer, size.Width * rowIndex, dataBox.DataPointer + dataBox.RowPitch * rowIndex, size.Width));
    dataStream.Dispose();
    texture.Device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(texture, 0);
}
```

I also googled a lot about this, found similar posts like this: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/573961-how-to-set-depth-value-in-pixel-shader/ however couldn't managed solve it on my side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write to the depth buffer, you need to target the SV_Depth system-value semantic. So your pixel shader output struct would look more like the following:

```
struct PS_OUT
{
    float4 color : SV_Target;
    float depth : SV_Depth;
};
```

And the shader would not specify SV_Target as in your example (the SV_ outputs are defined within the struct). So it would look like:

```
PS_OUT PS(VS_OUT input)
{
    PS_OUT output = (PS_OUT)0;

    output.color = m_TextureColor.SampleLevel(m_TextureSampler, input.texcoord, 0);

    // Now that output.depth is defined with SV_Depth, and you have depth-write enabled,
    // this should write to the depth buffer.
    output.depth = m_TextureDepth.SampleLevel(m_TextureSampler, input.texcoord, 0);

    return output;
}
```

Note that you may incur some performance penalties on explicitly writing to depth (specifically on AMD hardware) since that forces a bypass of their early-depth hardware optimization. All future draw calls using that depth buffer will have early-Z optimizations disabled, so it's generally a good idea to perform the depth-write operation as late as possible.

Comment: I'm very aware of performance penalties, however there's no other way, because the API streams this to me. Thank you very much!